# How to access the logged in principal from HttpSessionListener with Java EE Security?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have an application with `@CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition`, and I would like to log the username, session id, IP address, etc. both at login and at logout. The HttpAuthMechanism that gets applied with this annotation associate the given session with the principal, which I can access through the `SecurityContext`. With a direct logout, I have no problem logging, but I would also like to log when session times out. So I created a HttpSessionListener and in its `sessionDestroyed()` method I try to access the logged in user through `SecurityContext`, but it returns an empty set, maybe because the securityContext got invalidated already.

One solution I have in my mind is to store the user principal in a session parameter (which likely happens with the `HttpAuthMechanism` implementation) and access it from there from the `HttpSessionEvent` object, but that doesn't feel like the cleanest solution. Is there another Listener I can use or some other solution?

Comment: I didn't say anything about sessionCreated, but sessionDestroyed does mean logout for that user.

Answer (score -1):

I went with the custom HttpAuthenticationMechanism, here is it if anyone would need it *(though I would be more than glad to have some feedback on whether or not it has any security flaws, or improvements)*.

In an `@ApplicationScoped` class implementing `HttpAuthenticationMechanism`:

```
@Override
public AuthenticationStatus validateRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpMessageContext httpMessageContext) throws AuthenticationException {
    if (!httpMessageContext.isProtected()) {
        return httpMessageContext.doNothing();
    }
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    Credential credential = httpMessageContext.getAuthParameters().getCredential();

    // If we already have a session, we get the user from it, unless it's a new login
    if (session != null && !(credential instanceof UsernamePasswordCredential)) {  
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
        if (user != null) {
            return httpMessageContext.notifyContainerAboutLogin(user, user.getRoles());
        }
    }

    // If we either don't have a session or it has no user attribute, we redirect/forward to login page
    if (!(credential instanceof UsernamePasswordCredential)) {
        return redirect(request, response, httpMessageContext);
    }

    // Here we have a Credential, so we validate it with the registered IdentityStoreHandler (injected as idStoreHandler)
    CredentialValidationResult validate = idStoreHandler.validate(credential);

    Context context = new Context();
    context.setIp(request.getRemoteAddr());

    if (validate.getStatus() == CredentialValidationResult.Status.VALID) {
        session = request.getSession(true);
        CallerPrincipal callerPrincipal = validate.getCallerPrincipal();
        session.setAttribute("user", callerPrincipal);


        context.setUser(callerPrincipal);
        context.setSessionId(session.getId());

        Logger log = new Logger(logger, "validateRequest", context);

        log.debug("Logged in user: " + callerPrincipal.getName());

        String redirectPage = "whatYouWant.xhtml";

        redirect(request, response, httpMessageContext, redirectPage);

        return httpMessageContext.notifyContainerAboutLogin(validate);
    } else if (validate.getStatus() == CredentialValidationResult.Status.NOT_VALIDATED) {
        return redirect(request, response, httpMessageContext);
    } else {
        // Logging
        return httpMessageContext.responseUnauthorized();
    }
}
```

And in an implemented `HttpSessionListener`:

```
 @Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    User user = (User) se.getSession().getAttribute("user");

    if (user != null) {
        // logging
    }
}
```